# properties of tensor product as an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let's take the following $\mathbb{Q}$-module:  $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} G$, where G is any abelian group.  How to show that it is torsion-free abelian group (even in the case $G$ is not torsion-free)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and suppose $n (1 \otimes g)=0$ in $\mathbb{Q} \otimes G$. Then

$$ 1 \otimes g = \frac{n}{n} (1 \otimes g) = \frac{1}{n} (n (1 \otimes g)) = \frac{1}{n}(0)=0 .$$

Comment: sure, an arbitrary element of the tensor product is a linear combination of primitives like this one, but I don't think that changes the proof.

Comment: The most general form of an element in $\mathbb{Q}\otimes G$ is $\frac{1}{a}\otimes g$, for integer $a>0$ and $x\in G$.

Comment: @egreg, just for any element $x \in \mathbb{Q} \otimes G$ of finite order, from $nx=0$, it follows that $x=\frac{n}{n}x=\frac{1}{n}(nx)=0$, so that the general form plays no role

Comment: @Anna I agree; my comment was to make clear that $1\otimes g$ is not a generic element of $\mathbb{Q}\otimes G$.